How is the SVM optimization objective derived from the hinge loss function?
The hinge loss function, in the context of SVMs, is given as:
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{\vec w}, b\,; \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)}, y ^{(i)}) = \max(0, 1-y ^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w}\cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b))
$$
The corresponding cost function will be given as:
$$
J(\mathbf{\vec w}, b) = \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{\vec w}\|^{2}_{2} + C\sum_{i=1}^{m}\max(0, 1 - y ^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w}\cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b))
$$
From here we can state the optimization objective as:
$$
\min _{\mathbf{\vec w, b}} J(\mathbf{\vec w}, b) = \min _{\mathbf{\vec w}, b} \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{\vec w}\|^{2}_{2} + C\sum_{i=1}^{m}\max(0, 1 - y ^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w}\cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b))
$$
However, the primal optimization objective is typically given as:
$$
\begin{align}
& \min _{\mathbf{\vec w}, b} \frac{1}{2} \|\mathbf{\vec w}\|^{2}_{2} \\
& \text{s.t.}\; y ^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b) \ge 1 \; \forall i \in \mathbb{N}_{m}
\end{align}
$$
From here we can derive the dual optimization objective using the Lagrange Multipiers Method and KKT conditions.
My question is how is the primal optimization objective as formulated above derived from the hinge cost function?
Moreover, why is the regularization constant not a part of the primal optimization objective even though it is a part of the dual optimization objective(as a constraint)?
